# How do i use Checkboxes in gridview to show data

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

I Have Two Gridview in first one there is some data with checkbox. I Want when i check two or more checkboxes then show the both record who's checked to another gridview There is my Coding. Problem is it's show only one record at a time..

```
    protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

    foreach(GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)

    {

     if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow )

      {

       CheckBox chkSelect = (CheckBox)row.Cells[0].FindControl("CheckBox1");

       if (chkSelect != null)

       {

         if (chkSelect.Checked)

         {

           string FoodItem = ((Label)row.FindControl("Label1")).Text.ToString(); 
           string s = "select * from Item where Item_Name='" + FoodItem + "' "; 
           db.grid(s, GridView2);

         }

       }

    }

  }
```

Comment: the line: db.grid(s, GridView2); refer to function you created called 'grig'? if so, can you provide the code of this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking your code,

first think dont bind gridview immediately after checking checked property of each check box, it will override gridview2. first collect all check box values by concatinating say FoodItem = "(value1,value2,value3)".

call data base one time by modifying query like

```
string s = "select * from Item where Item_Name in " + FoodItem +"; 
db.grid(s, GridView2);
```

I think you have multiple selection so keep seperate button and write all codes to copy from one grid to another grid inside button click event.